# Замена с помощью re.sub ()

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, re

Нужно ввести массив значений в **pattern** из **re.sub(pattern, repl, string)** не знаю, как это можно реализовать пробовал вот так:

```
from re import sub
def filter_words(phrase):
   for word in "bad|mean|ugly|horrible|hideous".split("|"):
       if word in phrase.lower():
           return sub(word,"awesome",phrase)
```

Пример работы кода: мы вводим строку **"You said he was a bad dog."** ---> **"You said he was a awesome dog."**

И аналогичная замена происходит со всеми словами из этой строки **"bad|mean|ugly|horrible|hideous"**.

Comment: 1. перестаньте ставить пробелы между методом и скобками (split(), например). Для того, чтобы найти слово во фразе с помощью `in`, нужно само фразу разбить на слова для начала.

Comment: Не понятно что вы хотите. Приведите примеры, пожалуйста.

Comment: Я привел пример работы функции.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В регулярных выражения для поиска **целых слов**, их нужно оборачивать в `\b`.

В `PATTERN_TEXT` будет такой шаблон:

> \bbad\b|\bmean\b|\bugly\b|\bhorrible\b|\bhideous\b

Пример:

```
import re

WORDS = "bad", "mean", "ugly", "horrible", "hideous"
PATTERN_TEXT = '|'.join(fr"\b{word}\b" for word in WORDS)
PATTERN = re.compile(PATTERN_TEXT, flags=re.IGNORECASE)


def filter_words(phrase):
    return PATTERN.sub("awesome", phrase)


print(filter_words("You said he was a bad dog."))
# You said he was a awesome dog.

print(filter_words("You said he was a badass dog."))
# You said he was a badass dog.
```

---

Если нужно без полного совпадения по слову, то нужно убрать `\b`:

```
import re

WORDS = "bad", "mean", "ugly", "horrible", "hideous"
PATTERN = re.compile('|'.join(WORDS), flags=re.IGNORECASE)


def filter_words(phrase):
    return PATTERN.sub("awesome", phrase)


print(filter_words("You said he was a bad dog."))
# You said he was a awesome dog.

print(filter_words("Go on Tony you, horribleish person!"))
# Go on Tony you, awesomeish person!
```

Comment: А если надо заменить часть слова ? По типу **'Go on Tony you, horribleish person!'** ---> **'Go on Tony you, awesomeish person!'**

Comment: Можете добавить второй пример для работы с частями слов в предложениях было бы интересно посмотреть реализацию в коде.

Comment: Тогда, не нужно добавлять `\b`, добавлю пример

Comment: Нашел еще вот такой вариант решения, что значит **r** и **?i** в этом коде **sub(r"(bad|mean|ugly|horrible|hideous)(?i)","awesome",phrase)**

Comment: `r` -- raw string, это питоничье, оно не позволяет экранировать символы через \ . а `(?i)` -- это чисто из регулярок, тоже самое что `flags=re.IGNORECASE`, но просто описывается в строка шаблона